# HtmlEncode error on a generated view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've just set up a small R&D MVC2 project, and I've basically used only the wizards to add a partial view for my `Customer` object, which as a Linq to SQL entity.  When I try and visit the Create view for Customer, I get the following error on the RenderPartial method in the Create view:

*Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string)' has some invalid arguments*

The `Create` view looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <%: Html.RenderPartial("CustomerEditorExplicit") %>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

And `CustomerEditorExplicit` looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>            
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerId) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerId) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerId) %>
    </div>
```

etc.

I also have a `CustomerEditorModel` looking like below, but also gives me the same error:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("CustomerEditorExplicit") %>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Just remove the Colon after the code blocks before you render your partial.

You may need to add a semi colon to the end of that line too.

Comment: The colon on the textboxes is fine, but not on RenderPartial, thanks.  The return type of RenderPartial is 'void', where TextBoxFor returns a System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString value.